# Pressing back in browser (laravel app) causes an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It's so weird.  When a user is logged out of my application, press back to the previous page, which is user/login I get this error:

```
{"error":
{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
"message":"Call to a member function with() 
on a non-object","file":"\/home\/nicola\/projects\/pensions\/app\/controllers\/UserController.php",
"line":79}}
```

The page isn't being reloaded though.  I put a `die()` in the application and it doesn't hit it, so the error must be being generated from the cached version.  However when browsed to directly, there is no problem accessing user/login.  It's only when pressing back.

line 72 is:

`$this->layout->with($this->data);`

Which basically means it is saying layout isn't an object.

Layout is made into a view object in the base controller:  ` $this->layout = \View::make($this->layout);

**EDIT** `

```
//the function causing the error
public function getLogin ()
{

    $this->data['page_title'] = 'user/login';

    $this->layout->with($this->data);//line 72

    $this->layout->content = \View::make('user.login', $this->data);
}



//function that makes the $layout an object in base controller

    protected function setupLayout ()
{


    if (!is_null($this->layout) && !\Request::ajax()) {

        $this->layout = \View::make($this->layout);            
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you look at the line that the issue is on? the problem is you are calling Auth::user()->with I am guessing (no idea why you would).
You need a filter on the pages that a guest isn't allowed to view. An auth filter.

Comment: Yeah may you please post the code around line 79 of UserController.php?

Comment: I don't help without all code, usually on #laravel. Because I know I will be able to just tell you the issue if I see all code.

Comment: yes but it's not like it's an error with my code, it seems like a caching issue.  I'm not sure how caching works to be honest.  I mean it runs then when accessing the cached page via the back button, it doesn't.  That is weird behaviour.

Comment: but it is an error in your code...

Comment: my code works fine though when accessing pages through urls, it's only when pressing back.  That's what is confusing.

Comment: Read above where if I see your code I'll tell you the issue. Or just be confused more and claim your code has no error.

Comment: Ok, I've added in my code.

Comment: figured it out.  It's the `if(!\Request::ajax()){}` line.  Pressing back seems to come through to laravel as if it's an ajax request.

Comment: So do you know why pressing back is mimicking an ajax call?